# Persistent volume with Heroku Dynos

Tags: heroku, dyno

My Java application is built around an embedded database which stores db data directly to disk. I understand that Heroku by default is built on an *ephemeral filesystem* and anything stored in it will be removed when dynos restart or just don't stick.

What is the workaround to make such an application available and deployed in Heroku?

Answer (score 1):

> I understand that Heroku by default is built on an *ephemeral filesystem*

This isn't "by default". It's fundamental to [Heroku's architecture](https://blog.heroku.com/twelve-factor-apps) and cannot be changed. Heroku is designed to be trivially horizontally scalable, and part of that design is that state should exist apart from any one dyno. Dynos are disposable.

> What is the workaround to make such an application available and deployed in Heroku?

As far as I know, none exists. Either change how you save your data or choose another host.

(You *might* be able to mount a shared persistent filesystem on your dynos, but that's awkward and undermines Heroku's architecture. I don't advise it. None of Heroku's [offical addons](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/) provides a persistent filesystem, and a quick search finds a few blog posts outlining attempts but I don't see any successes.)